# Small RSA or DSA lib without dependencies

Tags: c, encryption, rsa

Is there a small library for RSA or DSA without any dependencies like GMP or OpenSSL? (Written in C or Asm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [axTLS](http://axtls.sourceforge.net/) it's a BSD licensed TLSv1 SSL in C for embedded systems. It's built for POSIX sockets, but is easily ported.

The one thing it's missing is RSA key generation, but it can read X.509 certificates.

It's about 32KB of code space with a small RAM footprint.

Answer (score 9):

You may find `LibTomCrypt` useful.  It's written in C, supports RSA and DSA (along with a host of other algorithms), and is public domain software.  You can read about it [here](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt).

Comment: Ahh, another one I tried before, but as I said I need plain RSA/DSA.

Comment: Looks like this one is gone.  The site appears to be parked and squatted.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found myself one after searching not so common coder sites http://z0mbie.daemonlab.org/ it's under PGP/RSA-RELATED if someones interested. But are there any others?

Comment: Erm, well I read code before I use it in my apps and why should I not use it if it works and is open source? I personally think the source of code does not matter but the code itself.

Comment: Any good programmer and security researcher DOES read such stuff. Thanks man for this link. Looks great, but I wish I had found a tiny rsa implementation in C there