# Public key implementation in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, encryption, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to use public key crypto to sign and later verify a file. The file is a simple plaintext file that contains user information for authoring purposes.

I tried different sites for a C implementation of a public key crypto algorithm but I haven't found anything. A lot of sites point to using certificates (x.509, etc) but that is way beyond what I need. I am just looking for a way to generate and public and private keys and use a relatively well known algorithm to sign and verify a file.

Any pointers to a pure C implementation out there? The focus is on code that I can reuse and not external libs. The main problem being that I don't want to have to link against a full lib and its dependencies in order to have a very basic public key system.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @frunsi for fixing the typo

Comment: So let's sum up: you're looking for a public-domain library which you can use in your closed-source application on an open-source operating system?

Comment: I don't really care for open source for this project. adding GPLed source would make me have to partially publish the code I am writing and I can't since I am not doing it for an open source project. Why is this so hard to answer? Is there a public key algorithm (RSA, DSA, El Gamal, other) implementation in C that contains ONLY that algorithm and doesn't bring a gazillion other features and is not a library that brings zillion dependencies that I can check? If you don't think there is one the say so. Thanks.

Comment: Write your own using GMP as suggested below.

Comment: and so it goes. Ok. thanks for the help. I should have known better than to come ask at stackoverflow. I was hoping I wouldn't have to "roll my own" but I guess I will have to.

Comment: which one is your answer Flavius? Oh, yeah you did NOT provide one. I'll accept whatever was first and I'm out of here.

Comment: @Flavius: Care to comment on what is wrong with closed-source application on an open-source operating system?

Comment: @MrAleph: Just implementing the biginteger arithmetic alone will take up a fair amount of code, e.g. a "full lib".

Comment: @GregS: Nothing. Just don't complain that the community is not willing to support it (i.e. by creating a library which can be used in a closed-source environment). Sounds fair to me, doesn't it to you? Yes, there are a few libraries which allow that. Say thanks for them and move on. If there aren't ... say thanks for the great open platform ... and move on.

Comment: I'm not sure why the OpenSSL only answer was accepted, rather than mine, which provided several alternatives since you explicitly said you did not want OpenSSL

Comment: @samoz I just accepted the 1st answer given since none of them were useful and I was getting tired of Flavius. Besides people tend not to read the questions and just answer. I was very clear with what I needed and none answered that. True, you gave an honest answer other than just "use openssl" but it still did not help me. Do you want me to accept yours? Sure.

Comment: There @samoz, now you have the answer accepted

Comment: To everyone else, NO openSSL is **not** the way to go. And it might not be GPL but the license still restricts me from using parts of the code. In any case the code is WAY to spaghetti for me to even begin to use it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is a very good package. You can just use the crypto library portion, which provides basic RSA implementations. That might be in line with what you are looking for.

[Cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) is another alternative that could work for you. It has some strange licensing issues though, so consider those depending on how you will be using it.

[Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) is a set of different crypto technologies, and includes RSA, so you might try that.

Finally, RSA is not terribly complex to implement, so you could even implement it yourself using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which provides the necessary mathematical functions you would need.

Comment: Agreed, OpenSSL is the way you want to go.

Comment: I tried that already. 2 problems. 1) I don't want to have to link against the full openssl lib so I can have a basic public key functionality and 2) I can't force any of the computers where the program will run to have to have openssl installed. Several of the boxes I dealt with don't have it. That's why I am looking for code I can use with my own code.

Comment: @Mr Aleph: If it comes to cryptography, the oldest and most peer-reviewed code is probably the one you want to go with and OpenSSL definitely is a well-respected library. Statically linking it into your application should not cost too much memory, actually.

Comment: Only it does and it brings with it a huge set of dependencies that may or may not be present in all computers.

Comment: @samoz OpenSSl, I stated why I can't use it. Cryplib I am looking at it right now. Crypto++ is C++ and would bring the whole C++ runtime into a C app and I can't do that.

Comment: Thanks. No libraries if possible. Ok. I am out I guess there is no way to do this then without having to deal with horrendous dependencies, huge chucks of code that are useless to me or 3rd party libraries that  are bigger than my whole program.

Comment: Okay, I just don't get who's downvoting these answers.  I guess we'll never know...

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at the well-respected, debugged, and tested [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) libraries.  Although OpenSSL is primarily for SSL/TLS networking, it contains extremely good implementations of many cryptographic protocols, which are often used by themselves for general cryptography.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoters- Can you please explain what is wrong with this answer (especially since another answer giving the same link/answer just got upvoted?)  I'd like to improve this answer if at all possible.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this question. It wasn't me. Anyway, thanks for the answer but I don't think OpenSSL is a viable solution for what I need. See what I answered previously.

Comment: Too sad this happens, SO becomes more and more a place of gangs. Everyone is bringing his homies...

Comment: @template - I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, but I'll vouch for you.  I note that your answer was actually before samoz's answer, so if "OpenSSL" is the accepted answer, yours should probably be selected over that one. You might improve your answer by linking to the appropriate components in the OpenSSL docs, like [rsa(3)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html#) and the associated [RFC 2437](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2437).

Comment: @KevinVermeer Thanks but I can't, it's GPL. Besides I've been playing with it for several days and in order to use the public crypto part I need to bring so much extra code and external libs that it is ridiculous.

Comment: @Flavius I use stackoverflow as my last resort since in the past few months people just downvote questions that are actually important for no apparent reason. Also, the people *answering* the questions tend *not* to answer and simple ask the annoying "why do you need this" or "why do you want to do this". Even when I purposely write in the question why I want to do X or that I can't use a specific technology they tell me to use that... Too bad, stackoverflow used to be great.

Comment: I'd just like to note that I did in fact vote up for you templatetypedef, as we both answered similarly initially

Comment: Accepting this one because it was the 1st answer. This doesn't really help me no any of the answers. Thank all.

Comment: @MrAleph: Openssl is not GPL, and it's [license](http://www.openssl.org/source/license.html) is not like the GPL. Also, you can extract the source code of just the parts you need, though it is not trivial.

Comment: Like I said in the answers below, you CANNOT extract code from openSSL, it's impossible, you will bring with the code you need an endless amount of functions that i don't need nor I have the time to try to figure out what each does.

Answer (score 2):

DJ Bernstein's [curve25519](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html) lets you create public/private key pairs. It does not have functions for signing, but you should be able to figure that part out with not too much hassle.

*Update: In the mean time, there's also [Ed25519](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) which already has the signature generation stuff figured out, without you having to jump through hoops. Same author, same availability of software (also e.g. "Donna" implementation and python binding), same ease of use, comparable speed.*

The original implementation as well as the "Donna" implementation are both available under very liberal licenses.

You need to compile one file and call exactly one function to generate a key pair, and it's very fast. No obscure requirements for the public key. All one ever needs for some "cheap, fast, easy public key crypto".

Answer (score 2):

I think that there was an answer[1] that fitted your question on :: [Small RSA or DSA lib without dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735374/small-rsa-or-dsa-lib-without-dependencies)

> You may find LibTomCrypt useful. It's written in C, supports RSA and
>   DSA (along with a host of other algorithms), and is public domain
>   software. You can read about its features here: http://libtom.org/?page=features

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735526/68338 ( courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/users/33837/emerick-rogul )

Answer (score 1):

The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613361/open-source-code-for-rsa-implementation-in-c-c-use-library-or-write-my-own) contain some interesting links to other libraries.

However, I remember that there exists some reference source code in C for RSA and private key cryptography. I will add a link as soon as I have found it ;-)

**EDIT**

I just found "this link" (http://www.hackchina.com/en/cont/93068 - open on your own risk) - not sure about the source and details of that code. But, however, in the past the link to the original RSA reference implementation was contained somewhere in OpenSSL source or its documentation. Which is based on [cryptsoft.com](http://cryptsoft.com/)'s library. I am sure the source can still be found somewhere on [www.rsa.com/rsalabs/](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2002) - but I could not find it, and I am running out of time for now. Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Again, I'm trying to use the code to sign a file. I don't need to bring a huge chunk of code to have pseudo random generators, 4 different block ciphers, etc.

Comment: FYI if you go to that hackchina site it'll try to install a nice piece of malware. Thanks. If you didn't see it, chances are that you are now infected.