# Which is the encryption method used on /etc/shadow?

Tags: c, linux, encryption

Which is the encryption method used on `/etc/shadow` on GNU/Linux systems? I would like to write a small program for personal purpose that uses the same API, but at the moment I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution is man 3 crypt, MD5. I wanted to know if anyone has experience with these APIs!!!

Comment: This is useful for my purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565427/c-crypt-function

Comment: very informative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794588/public-key-implementation-in-c-for-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the [`crypt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function. On glibc, the method used depends on the salt, if it starts with:

- $1$: it uses MD5.
- $5$: it uses SHA-256.
- $6$: it uses SHA-512.
- $2a$: it uses blowfish, not supported everywhere.
- Otherwise it uses DES.

Comment: The method used to "encrypt" the password plaintext does not depend on the salt! The string between the first pair of $s indicates the "encryption" method, the string between the second pair of $s is the actual salt for that "encryption" method.

Comment: @fpmurphy: the second parameter to `crypt()` is called `salt`, and it includes an encryption algorithm identifier and the real salt.

Comment: Up 1 it was useful to find the what type of algorithm is used in my encryption. Thanks dude.

Comment: And `$y$` is for `yescrypt`

Answer (score 6):

Multiple encryption methods are available in glibc, see man 3 crypt, the Glibc Notes section: http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/crypt.3.html

When verifying an existing password, just pass the encrypted form as salt; only the initial $id$salt part will be used. When creating new password, initialize id with whatever you need and put some random characters in salt.

Answer (score 4):

basic example with crypt()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STR 256
#define MAX_SALT 12

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[MAX_STR];
    char salt[MAX_SALT];

    printf("salt: ");
    scanf("%s", salt);

    printf("password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    printf("Encrypt '%s' : '%s'\n", password, crypt(password, salt));

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compile program:

```
$ gcc -lcrypt test.c
```

Comment: info about headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127921/is-the-crypt-function-declared-in-unistd-h-or-crypt-h

Answer (score -1):

I receive

> undefined reference to `crypt'

so I think that you should compile with

`$ gcc test.c -lcrypt`