# Extract SHA-512 hash from /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, encryption

I saw on [Which is the encryption method used on /etc/shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660851/which-is-the-encryption-method-used-on-etc-shadow) that encrypted passwords starting with $6$ uses SHA-512 encryption.

Here is an example :

```
$6$5l70Gupv$xBTxhCSexudn5jJ9hampIfTK0KIR3nqK1K1Rxye.OA5obtKArO7jgftjJtVSdp31MPxItEPmOuWhbgBvp0wqn.
```

`xBTxhCSexudn5jJ9hampIfTK0KIR3nqK1K1Rxye.OA5obtKArO7jgftjJtVSdp31MPxItEPmOuWhbgBvp0wqn.` is supposed to be the actual hash. `5l70Gupv` being the salt.

However this does not look like a SHA-512 hash to me. Here is one generated from [this site](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha512.html) :

```
f8e3183d38e6c51889582cb260ab825252f395b4ac8fb0e6b13e9a71f7c10a80d5301e4a949f2783cb0c20205f1d850f87045f4420ad2271c8fd5f0cd8944be3
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: The /etc/shadow hash is (modified) base64 encoded, the one from the website is hex-encoded. Please don't call this encryption, hashing and encryption are different.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=32) explaining md5 vs md5crypt, which is the exact same issue for a different algorithm. There's also a [follow up](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=33) that subsequently compares this to SHA512crypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two different formats of two different algorithms.

- The `/etc/shadow` hash is SHA512crypt in a customized base64 encoding.
- The hash you calculated is a SHA-512 hash in hex notation.

They look visually different because they are formatted differently, and since the hashing algorithms are different, they can not be compared even if you use the same format for both.