# Small portable digital signing and verification library

Tags: c, public-key-encryption

I'm looking for a library that allows me to authenticate data sent to embedded modules. Due to the hardware constraints, it needs to be of small footprint (both code and memory wise) and yet have security comparable to RSA-1024.

The requirements are as follows

- Verification on embedded modules (custom CPUs, with only a C89 compiler available)
- Signing and verification in Windows (C/C++ code)
- Signing in Java (some data needs to be generated via a webpage, so Java would be a big perk)

I would very much like to not have to implement a PKCS #1 v1.5/PSS-like system myself, but I haven't been able to find any good libraries that match the above requirements. Open source would be nice, but commercial solutions are of equal interest. Note that I need access to the C-code, since it has to be recompiled for the custom CPUs.

[NaCl](http://nacl.cace-project.eu/) looks promising, but it seems to be in development still.

I've had a look at [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), but it does a lot more than digital signatures and stripping out just the signature verification code was non-trivial.

Am I looking at it the wrong way?
I tried implementing SHA+RSA first, but I wasn't sure if the padding step was correct (which means that it probably wasn't secure), so I decided to post here instead for help.

EDIT: Clarification, only the verification part have the tough constraints on it. Signature and key generation will run on normal PCs.

Comment: how did you solve the logic?.. now i am in need for the same.  it would be helpful for me if you send me some usefull links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can implement such a kind of solution is related to CPU and memory architecture that we have available, therefore would have to tell me more about your system. The first way would be to develop this on the cloud. Another alternative would be [SCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scl/). Also, you can found some answers on [Small RSA or DSA lib without dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735374/small-rsa-or-dsa-lib-without-dependencies)

Comment: SCL is C++, so it's not useful for me unfortunately.
That thread was nice, but I'm looking for something inbetween a simple RSA implementation and a full-blown SSL/cryptography package.
Not having to care about certificates would be nice (since the embedded modules will most likely have the public key embedded with them).

Comment: I'll accept the answer since it's close to what I'm looking for at least, although it doesn't get me all the way

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) (formerly known as PolarSSL):

> mbed TLS (formerly known as PolarSSL) makes it trivially easy for developers to include cryptographic and SSL/TLS capabilities in their (embedded) products, facilitating this functionality with a minimal coding footprint.

Comment: I checked it out a few months back but there was something that didn't fit what I was looking for.I'll take a closer look at it though. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to trust commercial products that don't actually list licensing prices.

Comment: It's also sketchy that "be told about security problems" is a premium commercial feature.

Comment: Website seems to have expired certificate (out of business?)

Comment: Updated link to current web site. I don't use this; just mentioning it, as I took a look at this back in 2012 or so.